# What should the 'parent' value be when calling Google's API keys client ListKeysRequest method?

Tags: google-cloud-python, google-cloud-api-keys

I'm trying to use the `google-cloud-api-keys` package's [`ApiKeysClient`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/apikeys/latest/google.cloud.api_keys_v2.services.api_keys.ApiKeysClient) to get a list of API keys in my project. What should the format of the `parent` parameter be?

I've tried using my project ID and project number, but I'm getting an `API_SHARED_INVALID_PARENT_FORMAT` error. I've tried all the following:

```
client.list_keys(parent='projects/12345') # projects / project number
client.list_keys(parent='projects/my-project') # projects / project ID
client.list_keys(parent='12345') # just the project number
client.list_keys(parent='my-project') # just the project ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered now that it should be `"projects/<project-id>/locations/global"` from looking at the [source code](https://github.com/turbot/steampipe-plugin-gcp/blob/06424588915e4c9c0bec56f90947da461ec0ee30/gcp/table_gcp_apikeys_key.go#L140C73-L140C73) of an open source project that calls this API route.

This works:

```py
from google.cloud import api_keys_v2
client = api_keys_v2.ApiKeysClient()
response  = client.list_keys(parent='projects/my-project-id/locations/global')
for r in response:
    print(r)
```